# Thunderbird: How to recover email passwords if master-password is known?

Tags: data-recovery, restore, sql, sqlite, mozilla

I forgot one of my email passwords. And it's still saved in Thunderbird that ran on Kubuntu. But now my Kubuntu is broken, and I cannot open thunderbird's GUI. The only thing I know is username and password I used to open a new session on my broken Kubuntu installation. Anyway. So I tried hacking the file signons.sqlite containing my passwords, [using this tutorial on stackexchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/8819/222594).

I could follow all the steps of the tutorial, except of the last one. And since it's not allowed on stackexchange to ask extra questions with low reputation, I am writing it here.

```
echo "select encryptedUsername, encryptedPassword from moz_logins;" | sqlite3 ~/.thunderbird/*.default/signons.sqlite
```

So where in the integer string can I find the encrypted Username and Password? And how to use Kubuntu's username+password to simply decrypt my email login credentials? I don't want to use Thunderbird Password Decryptor, because I distrust this hacking software.

Comment: it's probably a better path to your end goal to try to solve the problem about Thunderbird not launching, rather than try to decrypt anything that's encrypted without having the decryption key: it's a practically impossible task.

Comment: I agree with what Nmath said. In addition, the sqlite database that's used in the tutorial you've found hasn't been used anymore for at least a few years. So unless your password stayed the same since about 2014, you won't find it in signons.sqlite, encrypted or not.

Comment: What's wrong with Kubuntu? Do you need to just reinstall it to solve your problem?

Comment: Kubuntu doesn't boot anymore. It's broken. I already found all the encrypted password hash strings for every email account in thunderbird's signons file. The only thing I need to know, how to decrypt them using Kubuntu's login password?

Comment: I can't help you with decryption. However, if you give me more details about "Kubuntu doesn't boot anymore"... maybe I can help. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema, thank you for offering. I would rather post that original problem as a new question, and thereafter would link it to you in this comment section.

Comment: @heynnema , here is that question: https://askubuntu.com/q/1196335/520965