# Installation: No EFI System Partition was found

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, kubuntu, kde

The old Kubuntu distro did not start anymore (or only in emergency mode) 
Dual boot partitions were taken over manually as they were, leaving bootloader unchanged on /dev/sda during installation. Then comes the message:

> No EFI System Partition was found. This system will likely not be able
>   to boot successfully, and the installation process may fail. Please go
>   back and add an EFI System Partition, or continue at your own risk.

What does that mean? It was started in EFI mode, which was pointed out by the GRUB menu at startup, and ..

> [ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo UEFI || echo BIOS
>   UEFI

New partition must be created especially for EFI GRUB 2/Basics (section "With EFI"). 
Can I do this in the installer or better in advance with GParted, can I uncheck the / or /home somewhere?

Comment: source of this question: https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/installation-keine-efi-system-partition-was-fo/

Comment: Hope he can read German.

Comment: Oh what a mess. I couldn't read ALL of the question, as Google Translator couldn't handle all of it. It sounds like: 1) you're working with an old installation, 2) Windows had been installed in BIOS/MBR mode, 3) You probably then enabled Secure Boot and tried to install Ubuntu (can't do it that way), and 4) you tried to manually partition a small 200G HDD with /opt, /home, etc. (bad idea for small disks). So far, have I got this correct?

Comment: How you boot install media, UEFI or BIOS/CSM is then how it installs. And you really want gpt with UEFI. UEFI wants gpt, not old MBR partitioning. You can partition in advance, but be sure to change to gpt from default MBR, but that erases drive. If you have partitions you do not want to overwrite you can convert a MBR drive to gpt.  UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance, new versions do not need swap partition:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation